# how to send ' (apostrophe) in viber public account api?

Tags: api, viber

when I send a text message using the below api, 
Resource URL

https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/send_message

Post data

```
{
   "auth_token": "4453b6ac1s345678-e02c5f12174805f9-daec9cbb5448c51r",
   "receiver": "01234567890A=",
   "type": "text",
   "text": "I'm a test user"
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
I%27m a test user
```

I think the symbols are encoded format.Is there any way to send '(apostrophe) or symbols using viber public account api?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
{
   "auth_token": "4453b6ac1s345678-e02c5f12174805f9-daec9cbb5448c51r",
   "receiver": "01234567890A=",
   "type": "text",
   "text": "I\'m a test user"
}
```